# How to fade out full screen multiple background imaged in a separate div tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some code which contains the loop of images undergoes fade out transition as `<ul>` tag contains `<li>` and within the `<span>` tags contains background images and it makes the continuous transition. Now, I want a footer and next elements which are preceding to the loop of images are independent to that position and it should be like as [inoutscripts.com](http://inoutscripts.com) . And mainly the EXPLORE button should scroll with the backgrounds whose position is fixed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pure CSS Fullscreen Fading Slideshow</title>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style class="cp-pen-styles">
    html {
      min-height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    body {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0
    }
    .slideshow {
      list-style: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .slideshow li span {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      color: transparent;
      float: left;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat: none;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 0;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
      -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
      animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
    }
    .slideshow li h3 {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 2;
      bottom: 150px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      font-size: 2em;
      font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #fff;
      -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
      -moz-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
      animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .slideshow li h3 {
        bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 2em;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
      .slideshow li h3 {
        font-size: 2em;
      }
    }
    .slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
      background-image: url(01.jpg);
    }
    .slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
      background-image: url(02.jpg);
      -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
      animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    .slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
      background-image: url(03.jpg);
      -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
      animation-delay: 12s;
    }
    .slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
      background-image: url(04.jpg);
      -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
      animation-delay: 18s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      }
      12.5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      37.5% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes imageAnimation {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      }
      12.5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      37.5% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      12.5% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      37.5% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes titleAnimation {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      12.5% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      37.5% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    .no-cssanimations .slideshow li span {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .sep {
      position: relative;
      top: 630px;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 1;
      color: white;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .mid {
      color: white;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 300px;
      left: 560px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 130px;
      height: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="slideshow">
      <li>
        <p class="mid">EXPLORE</p>
        <h3>Pure CSS Fullscreen Fading Slideshow</h3>
        <span></span> 
      </li>
      <li> <span></span> 
      </li>
      <li> <span></span> 
      </li>
      <li> <span></span> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sep">
    <center>
      <p>Hello How are you</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The .`sep` class is the footer and when the browser zooms out the footer doesn't be fixed in that position. I want when I scroll down a separate division which is apart from the background image div.

Comment: How about position: fixed; bottom: 0;

Comment: yeah i had used, but it overlapped the main content so i used  top:

Answer (score 0):

how's this look??

```css
/** New Styles**/

header, footer {
 width:100%;
 background:#5655C4;
 color:#fff;
 padding:20px;
}
.slideshow {
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px; /*Set the height of the slider*/
 position:relative;
 margin:0; /*Strips the default margin on <ul> elements */
}
section {
 padding:45px;
 text-align:center;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
 background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pure CSS Fullscreen Fading Slideshow</title>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style class="cp-pen-styles">
html { min-height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}

body { height: 100%;padding: 0;margin:0}
.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slideshow li h3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.slideshow li h3 {
  bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

.slideshow li h3 { font-size: 2em; }
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(01.jpg); }

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(02.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(03.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(04.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes 
imageAnimation {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
 12.5% {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 37.5% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
}
}
@keyframes 
imageAnimation {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
 12.5% {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 37.5% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
titleAnimation {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 12.5% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 37.5% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
}
}
@keyframes 
titleAnimation {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 12.5% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 37.5% {
 opacity: 0;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
}
}

.no-cssanimations .slideshow li span { opacity: 1; }
.sep{ 
  position: relative;
  top: 630px;
padding: 3px;
width: 100%; 
background-color: black;
opacity:1;
color: white;
 z-index: 2;
}
.mid{
   color: white;
   background-color: transparent;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 300px;
   left: 560px;
   border: 1px solid white;
   z-index: 999;
   width:130px;
   height: 25px;
   text-align:center;
   padding:10px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  I'm a header!!!!!
</header>
<div>
  <ul class="slideshow">
    <li>
      <p class="mid">EXPLORE</p>
      <h3>Pure CSS Fullscreen Fading Slideshow</h3>
      <span></span> </li>
    <li> <span></span> </li>
    <li> <span></span> </li>
    <li> <span></span> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- Stripped .sep -->
<section>
 I'm a section with some super cool content!!
</section>
<section>
 Oh look, another section...
</section>
<section>
 Yet again – that's right, you guessed it.
</section>
<footer>
 And now the footer...
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

By the looks of things, you were on the right path – perhaps you just got a little lost with positioning...